# In Gridview make a dropdownbox visible when a checkbox is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with 2 templatefields, one is a checkbox and the other is a dropdownlist. I want to be able to have the dropdownlist for that row visible if a user selects the checkbox.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Follow-up Needed" ItemStyle-Width="75px">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CBFollowUp" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Follow-Up Assignment" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListFollowUpUser" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

I tried to put the logic in the RowDataBound, but on a postback I lose the checkbox selection, but if I do !isPostBack on my Databind, then It won't fire RowDataBound when a checkbox is selected.

I'm not sure where and what logic I need to make to make this fluid, Do I need to do it in the OnCheckedChanged, or javascript?

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the `OnCheckChanged` event like you thought. First add it to your CheckBox.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CBFollowUp" runat="server"
  AutoPostBack="true"
  OnCheckChanged="CBFollowUp_CheckChanged" />
```

Then handle it in your codebehind. In here you would find your DropDownList that is within the same row as the CheckBox you just clicked and then hide/show it as necessary.

```
protected void CBFollowUp_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox CBFollowUp = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)CBFollowUp.NamingContainer;

    DropDownList DropDownListFollowUpUser = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownListFollowUpUser");
    DropDownListFollowUpUser.Visible = CBFollowUp.Checked;
}
```